# how to create anonymous list in swift, such as Kotlin

Tags: ios, swift, list, kotlin, immutability

While i were changing kotlin code to swift code. I had a problem with create abstract immutable list.

```
private interface A{
    val Id : Int
    val anotherValue : Int
}

private val anotherList : ArrayList<A>

override val idList: List<Int>
    get() = object : AbstractList<Int>() {
        override val size: Int
            get() = anotherList.size

        override fun get(index: Int): Int {
            return anotherList[index].Id
        }
    }
```

This code is create 'AbstractList' on call the 'idList' property. I intended not to take up any additional capacity except for the created instance's own.

I tried to migrating code as follows at Swift:

```
override var idList: [Int]{
    return self.anotherList.map{
        $0.Id
    }
}
```

However, this code takes up more memory, such as List Copy. How can i do?

Comment: Swift arrays are immutable, so you can simply return `self.anotherList`

Comment: @Paulw11 self.anotherList is different Type. I add the Type of anotherList. It's not the advice I wanted, but thank you.

Comment: Unless you are talking about millions of elements, it is simplest to just use the code you have. Otherwise you would need to implement a new struct or class that conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` and implement the appropriate `subscript` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `lazy` map:

```
let idList: LazyMapSequence<[A], Int> {
    self.anotherList.lazy.map(\.id)
}
```

I am pretty sure `lazy` gives you a lazy "view" of the array. And since this is a lazy sequence, the ids won't be computed until you need them. Also, because arrays are random access, if you need, say, the third id, the first and second id won't be computed.

Alternatively, and I think this is better, write your own `ArrayKeyPathView` collection:

```
struct ArrayKeyPathView<WrappedElement, KeyPathType> : RandomAccessCollection {
    subscript(position: Int) -> Element {
        get {
            wrapped[position][keyPath: keyPath]
        }
    }
    
    var startIndex: Int {
        wrapped.startIndex
    }
    
    var endIndex: Int {
        wrapped.endIndex
    }
    
    
    var indices: Range<Int> {
        wrapped.indices
    }
    
    typealias Index = Int
    typealias SubSequence = ArrayKeyPathView
    typealias Element = KeyPathType
    typealias Indices = Range<Int>
    
    private let wrapped: [WrappedElement]
    private let keyPath: KeyPath<WrappedElement, KeyPathType>
    
    init(_ array: [WrappedElement], keyPath: KeyPath<WrappedElement, KeyPathType>) {
        self.wrapped = array
        self.keyPath = keyPath
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let idList: ArrayKeyPathView<A, Int> {
    ArrayKeyPathView(self.anotherList, keyPath: \.id)
}
```

Since swift arrays are copy-on-write, just passing it to `ArrayKeyPathView` doesn't create a copy.

Comment: 'A' type is private so i can't  use LazyMapSequence<[A], Int> type at the 'idList' property, but the  'lazy.map' have return type generic T array, [T] . so i can solved the issue. Thanks